# Q: CPLEX: How to write 2 equation as 1 constiants

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am using CPLEX for solving MILP. Now I want to write these two equations using the same variables

[view the equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7MFp.png)

I tried to write it in to

(1st equation as)

```
ct20 : forall(r1 in request,r2 in request, m1 in deliveries, m2 in deliveries : m1!=m2, k1 in truck, k2 in truck:k1!=k2, j1 in truck, j2 in truck:j1!=j2)
  sum(p in plant, k1 in truck:k1!=k2, j1 in jobs:j1!=j2)(x[p][r1][m1][k1][j1]*start_load[k1][j1]) <= sum(p in plant, k2 in truck:k1!=k2, j2 in jobs:j1!=j2)(x[p][r1][m1][k1][j1]*start_load[k2][j2])
```

(2nd equation as)

```
&& sum(p in plant, k1 in truck:k1!=k2, j1 in jobs:j1!=j2)(x[p][r1][m1][k1][j1]*start_load[k1][j1]+load_time[p][k1]) 
    <= sum(p in plant, k2 in truck:k1!=k2, j2 in jobs:j1!=j2)(x[p][r1][m1][k1][j1]*start_load[k2][j2])
```

How to merge them as one, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know you may group constraints with `{` and `}`?

```
range r=1..10;

dvar int x[r] in 0..10;

subject to
{
forall(i in r) 
{
4<=x[i];

x[i]<=6;
}


}
```

Comment: I really don’t know. Thank you.